# Is it possible to use File_put_contents($fileName, $array) so that each item in the array gets put on a new line?

Tags: php, arrays, file

I am trying to rewrite a file with the contexts of an array but I want each item in the array to be on separate line. Is this possible to do?

I currently have the following:

```
file_put_contents('file.txt',$tempArray);
```

The array has the following contents:

```
$tempArray = ["xyz","zyx", "123"]
```

and I want the file to look like this in the end:

```
xyz
zyx
123
```

but I am getting it all on one line currently

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do
`file_put_contents('file.txt',implode(PHP_EOL,$tempArray));`
and you are fine.

- [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) takes a seperator and array-values then concates them like:
  `implode('+',array(1,2))` becomes `1+2`
- PHP_EOL is an predefined constant from php that defines "\n" on linux  and "\r\n" on windows

Comment: Worked! Thanks a lot